# .NET MVC 5 C# - Placing clickable icon next to column headings used to sort a list of items on page by Last Name etc.?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Here is the Razor code for the column header link that you click to sort:

```
    <th>@Html.ActionLink("Last Name", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.LNameSortParm, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }, new { title = "Sort by Last Name ascending" })</th>
```

but I would like to have an icon next to the link indicating the sorting that is taking place.  Something similar to a bootstrap glyphicon.  Thanks in advance for your answers, comments, or suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

```
    <th>@Html.ActionLink("Last Name", "Index", 
        new { sortOrder = ViewBag.LNameSortParm, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }, 
        new { title = "Sort by Last Name ascending" }) 
        <i class="the-icon-class"></i>
    </th>
```

If you need change the icon according to the sort order, you can declase a "className" variable and assign it a value depending on your ViewBag.LNameSortParm (I suppose that variable indicates the ascending or descending order).
So, you would have something like:

`...<i class="@className"></i>...`

## Update

```
@{
  var className = "";
  if(ViewBag.SortOrder.Equals("asc"))
  {
    className = "glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top";
  }
  else
  {
    className = "glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  That is a great logical answer.  Since I have very little experience coding in Razor, would you mind showing an example of the logic you suggested in the section below the code you posted?

Comment: I added an update with some logic that should go at the very top of your view. I did the same thing as you once I had to make sorting, but I realized that it was a lot of effort, there are many boundaries to test. So I decided to use a third-party library, [https://www.datatables.net/](https://www.datatables.net/), and forget paging, sorting and all that stuff, while keeping my views clean of low-level logic. (sorry if my english is poor)

Comment: Thanks for the update.  First I had to add the logic to my controller to get the sorting to be reversible (asc/desc).  Then, with your help, I was able to change the glyph-icon to match the sorting.  Data Tables looks great.  I will definitely be looking into that for future projects.